# SQL Server 2014 Native Client (12.0.0.0) - Any way to force Assembly Version (e.g. SqlConnectionString "Type System Version")?

Tags: ado.net, sqlclr, sql-server-2014, sqlclient

I am writing an application (using .NET Framework 4.5.2 + SQL Server 2014 installed locally). The application needs to support both SQL Server 2014 and previous versions.

When reading data using the inbuilt SQLCLR-types (`SqlGeometry`, `SqlGeography`, `SqlHierarchyID`), the standard ADO.NET methods (e.g. `DataReader.GetValues()`) use the **10.0.0.0** assembly, and throw an exception due to a mismatch with the loaded (v11 or v12) version.

The reasoning is documented (though it takes a while to spot) in the [Breaking Changes in SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179(v=sql.120)#Denali) (for the **11.0.0.0** assembly). For SQL Server 2012, there are three workarounds listed:

- Use `Type System Version=SQL Server 2012` in the [SQLConnection.ConnectionString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)
- OR: Use `app.config / runtime / assemblyBinding / dependentAssembly` to re-map **v10.0.0.0** to **v11.0.0.0**
- OR (not a very "neat" way to handle it): rewrite your own code to manually deserialize from a `SqlBytes` instance...

When developing from a computer with SQL Server 2014 installed, the assembly version is **v12.0.0.0**, and similar issues arise:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry` to type `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry`.

For SQL Server 2014 (other than the horrible manual *deserialize* approach), there only seems to be one workaround (not officially documented in the breaking-changes) - it would appear that the v4.5 `SqlConnection` hasn't yet caught up with the version of SQL Server:

- Use `app.config / runtime / assemblyBinding / dependentAssembly` to re-map **v10.0.0.0** to **v12.0.0.0**

**Question:** other than re-mapping **v10.0.0.0** to **v12.0.0.0** in `app.config` (which seems to work), is there any other (easier) approach that will use the referenced assembly version?

A quick code-example below shows the failure (without the assembly-remapping in place):

```cs
private static void DoStuff()
{
    SqlGeography geog_val = SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars("POLYGON((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))"), 4326);
    SqlGeometry geom_val = SqlGeometry.Parse("LINESTRING(1 1,2 3,4 8, -6 3)");

    prm_geog.Value = DBNull.Value; prm_geom.Value = geom_val; ReadReturnedSpatialColumns(cmd);
    prm_geog.Value = geog_val; prm_geom.Value = DBNull.Value; ReadReturnedSpatialColumns(cmd);
}

private static void ReadReturnedSpatialColumns(SqlCommand cmd)
{
  using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
  {
    dr.Read(); var items = new object[2]; dr.GetValues(items);
    var geog_test = dr.IsDBNull(0) ? SqlGeography.Null : (SqlGeography)items[0];
    var geom_test = dr.IsDBNull(1) ? SqlGeometry.Null : (SqlGeometry)items[1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue still exists with Framework 4.6.1 and there appears to be no workaround apart from the 3 you've already discovered. So the short answer to your question is **no**.

However I would question if you *really* need version 12 of the spatial types, because (as far as I can tell) they don't add anything over the v11 types. If you'd prefer to use the v11 types so you can use the `Type System Version=SQL Server 2012` workaround, you can install the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/) that incorporates all three versions (10, 11, 12) - it's specifically designed to allow you to deploy to servers where MSSQL may not be installed.

As a bonus, referencing that package directly and using `Type System Version=SQL Server 2012` will ensure that your app will always be using the 2012 spatial types, so upgrading to SQL 2016 won't break anything if it decides to return a different version of them (e.g. 13, or 14, or whatever 2016 will use) by default.

Comment: Thanks - although it is so long ago that I can't remember the original project, I do remember that there was a specific reason that I needed to support the full geography features (possibly to avoid the hemisphere restriction in earlier versions). 

Anyway, this is certainly a good clear answer, so thanks for your help.